# How to delete two tr elements?

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a html table like this:

```
 <table>
   <tr id='first'>
      <td>text</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>text</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>text</td>
   </tr>     
 </table>
```

I want to remove 2 tr elements at once something like this:

```
 <script>
    var tr = document.getElementById('first'),
        table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0],
        i=0;

    do {
      tr = table.tbody.removeChild(tr);
    } while ((tr = tr.nextSibling(tr)) && i++<2);
 </script>
```

But after first iteration `table.removeChild(tr)` returns null, so I can't get `tr.nextSibling(tr)`.

Please help me.

Comment: There two problems: (a) `tr` elements are not children of `table`, but of `tbody`. (b) Once you removed one of the elements, you cannot get its next sibling as it is not in the tree anymore.

Comment: (b). Ok. How can to add 2 tr to temporary array and remove at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should temporary save a reference to the next row, as shwn below. Also, to select the `tbody`, you have to use `tBodies[0]`.

```
var nextrow = document.getElementById('first'),
    table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0],
    i=0, tr;
while (nextrow && i++<2) {
  tr = nextrow;
  nextrow = tr.nextSibling;
  table.tbodies[0].removeChild(tr);
}
```

An alternative, universal solution:

```
var nextrow = document.getElementById('first'),
    i=0, tr;
while (nextrow && i++<2) {
  tr = nextrow;
  nextrow = tr.nextSibling;
  tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
}
```

Comment: Don't you have to initialise nextrow to stop the `tr = nextrow;` line corrupting the `tr` value first time round the loop?

Comment: @Alohci You're right. I have also replaced the `do-while` loop with a `while` loop, in case `#first` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should define the next tr to remove before removing the current tr.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194395/how-to-delete-two-tr-elements/8194449#8194449

Answer (score 0):

this works as well:

```
    var trs = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for(var i = 1; i < trs.length; i++){
        trs[i].parentNode.removeChild(trs[i]);
        i--;
    }
```